# Firebase database().ref() nonexistent path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, my app will be creating nested data all the time. My question is do I first have to check if a key exists before i can reference it, or can i just...

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("dataTree/" + childVar1 + "/" + childVar2);
ref.push({data: "this is data"});
```

and it will create the nested structure for me? i.e. :

```
{
    "dataTree": {
        "notChildVar1": {
            "someChildName": {
                "data": "test"
            }
        }
        "alsoNotChildVar1": {
            "someChildName": {
                "data": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should Become...

```
{
    "dataTree": {
        "notChildVar1": {
            "someChildName": {
                "data": "test"
            }
        }
        "alsoNotChildVar1": {
            "someChildName": {
                "data": "test"
            }
        }
        "childVar1": {
            "childVar2": {
                "data": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if the above code will return an error, what can i do to test if a key exists, add it if it does not exist, and then push something in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to any arbitrary location in the database, and any required nodes that do not exist will be created for you automatically.  You don't have to create each child node individually.

Similarly, if all children of a node are deleted, the node itself will be deleted automatically (there is no such thing as an "empty" child node).

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try something like create the full content of `childVar1` and insert directly in your database including the `childVar2: {data: test}` (I supposed that you're using RealtimeDatabase).

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("dataTree/" + childVar1);
ref.push(
   "childVar2": {
     "data": "this is data"
   }
);
```